# Angular: Query parameter value contains route value

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an URL which is like `http://example.com/login/?redirect="/user#account"`, so here I store `redirect` value and use that to navigate to that page after successful login. This works fine if `redirect` query don't have any `# (hash)` value in it, but if it has then it takes that #value and redirect to that route even if user is not logged, it should redirect to `http://example.com/login/#/login` if not logged in.

Comment: angularjs or angular2?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya its in Angular2/4

Comment: are you using `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: Dheeraj are you own getting what does the question mean to your self ?? Add more details to question like examples which can clarify it more with the example you tried to fix it .. and do not forget to add  comments the sections where you are getting the actual problem

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal you have to encode your url like `/user#account` `user%23account`

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal and don't use `""`

Comment: You may use a `Guard` that is allowing or deny the access and "remembering" the redirection URL in case the login is successful

Answer (score 0):

The way Angular 4 creates URL and routes is something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoadServers(id: number){
    this.router.navigate(['/servers', id, 'edit'],{queryParams: {allowEdit: '1'}, fragment: 'loading'});
  }

}
```

Due to the command **navigate** in *onLoadServers()* you will receive the following view of the route:

> http://localhost:4200/servers/1/edit?allowEdit=1#loading

As you can mention there is no "".

In the component loading by this route you can **receive** the query params and the fragment(**loading** - in this case) with:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);//{allowEdit:"1"}
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.fragment);//loading
}
```